# Setting up non-Basis conda environment in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

Well I thought I had set up my conda environment in Pycharm just like their [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html) require:

- Settings > Project Interpreter > Add
- Select Conda Environment
- Check existing environment
- Browse for interpreter path (in this case `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\python.exe`)
- Click OK

I did notice, however that the environment was not automatically called in the 'Terminal' tab in PyCharm. So I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392719/get-the-anaconda-prompt-running-in-the-pycharm-terminal) which seems to adequately set it up for the terminal (although in my opinion that should automatically be taken care of when I select the environment above).

Now the confusing part: I tried to run the following in 3 different places in pycharm. These are 1) regular script, 2) Python Console, and 3) Terminal (by doing `python` and forcing it into python interpreter mode`:

```
import os
print(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'])
```

For cases 1) and 2) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'CONDA_PREFIX'
```

For case 3) it runs fine and outputs the path for the conda environment:

`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36`

This indicates to me that although the right `python.exe` is used to run the interpreter, the necessary environment variables are not transferred automatically. I need these variables to do additional things, and I think the above explains why I have to add the following environment variables to my build configurations:

`GDAL_DATA`
`PROJ_LIB`

In the regular anaconda prompt/pycharm terminal these are already defined (as they originate from the batch scripts in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\etc\conda\activate.d`, but they are not defined in my main anaconda python interpreter.

How do I make sure the *entire* conda environment is defined in Pycharm as my main interpreter. I am talking complete with environment variables and any other shenanigans I am not aware of? The docs only indicate how you can set conda as your interpreter, and this is not enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you sorted it out in the last five months but in case anyone else is stuck...

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180357/1409983) explains how to get the **terminal** to activate a conda environment by passing the activate command into cmd.exe when the terminal starts:

> Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal.
>
> Replace the value in Shell path with cmd.exe "/K"
> C:\path\to\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat your_environment_name.
>
> [image: Pycharm terminal config]

The only reliable way I've found to make the **console** work correctly is to launch PyCharm from the activated environment. From a windows command prompt:

```
activate my-env-name && pycharm64.exe & 
#the trailing '&' causes pycharm to run in the background rather than freezing the terminal
```

Or from git-bash:

```
source activate my-env-name && pycharm64.exe &
```

Where `my-env-name` is the name of your conda environment.

Note that if you installed the 32 bit version you need to swap `pycharm64.exe` for `pycharm.exe`

You can make this a bit more repeatable by creating an "edit.sh" file in your project:

```
#!/bin/sh
source activate my-env-name && pycharm64.exe &
```

And then running that script when you want to run your project `cd my-project && bash edit.sh`

Comment: Links to answers break, which in this case would make your answer of little value. Can you include the relevant info in your answer? Thanks

Comment: @hat - sorry - thought that might be seen as plagiarism. Updated now!

Comment: So long as you give attribution, it is fine. SO answers are under CC BY-SA 4.0