# Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import _ssl DLL load fail error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I created anaconda environment with Python=3.7 and have trouble with the error of _ssl and DLL. When I tried to get back to my base environment, I have trouble getting the background processes to complete as shown in the figure below, this goes on forever.

[image: pycharm_0]

The error:

```
C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\HeisenbergPy37\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=63950
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\HeisenbergPy37\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

All packages installed with

> conda create -n  anaconda python=3.7

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\HeisenbergPy37:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2018.12                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astroid                   2.1.0                    py37_0
astropy                   3.1              py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py37_0
attrs                     18.2.0           py37h28b3542_0
babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                      py37_1
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py37_0
bitarray                  0.8.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3                   py37_0
bleach                    3.0.2                    py37_0
blosc                     1.14.4               he51fdeb_0
bokeh                     1.0.2                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h452e1ab_1
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               0.6.1                    py37_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0
cryptography              2.4.2            py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.63.0            h2a8f88b_1000
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.2           py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37hfa6e2cd_1
dask                      1.0.0                    py37_0
dask-core                 1.0.0                    py37_0
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1
distributed               1.25.1                   py37_0
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py37_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py37hfa6e2cd_2
filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1
flask-cors                3.0.7                    py37_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.3.7            py37he774522_1
glob2                     0.6                      py37_1
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h3bdd7fb_2
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.4.1                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
keyring                   17.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py37h6538335_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37hfa6e2cd_2
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.63.0            h2a8f88b_1000
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.35               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                h7a1dbc1_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                h36446d0_2
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0
llvmlite                  0.26.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hef2cd61_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.0            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.0.2            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.14           py37hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.1                      144
mkl-service               1.1.2            py37hb782905_5
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py37h6288b17_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py37he980bc4_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py37_1
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.2                      py37_1
nltk                      3.4                      py37_1
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  5.7.4                    py37_0
numba                     0.41.0           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.6.8            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.15.4           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0
odo                       0.5.1                    py37_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  2.5.12                   py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
packaging                 18.0                     py37_0
pandas                    0.23.4           py37h830ac7b_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0
partd                     0.3.9                    py37_0
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    5.3.0            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       18.1                     py37_0
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py37_1
pluggy                    0.8.0                    py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
prometheus_client         0.5.0                    py37_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                    py37_0
psutil                    5.4.8            py37he774522_0
py                        1.7.0                    py37_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py37_0
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0
pylint                    2.2.2                    py37_0
pyodbc                    4.0.25           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.3.0                    py37_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
pytables                  3.4.4            py37he6f6034_0
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.1                h8c8aaf0_6
python-dateutil           2.7.5                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6
pytz                      2018.7                   py37_0
pywavelets                1.0.1            py37h8c2d366_0
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000
pyyaml                    3.13             py37hfa6e2cd_0
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py37hfa6e2cd_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py37_0
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py37_0
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.11.0                   py37_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
scikit-image              0.14.1           py37ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py37h343c172_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py37h29ff71c_2
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
sphinx                    1.8.2                    py37_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1
spyder                    3.3.2                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.15           py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h452e1ab_0
sympy                     1.3                      py37_0
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0
tornado                   5.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0
tqdm                      4.28.1           py37h28b3542_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py37_1
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py37hfa6e2cd_2
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                    py37_0
xlwings                   0.15.1                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                he025d50_1
zict                      0.1.3                    py37_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: When exactly does this error occur?  You seem to have a *lot* more packages in this environment than would be installed by simply running: `conda create -n anaconda python=3.7`

Comment: @user9074332 no all these packages are installed with the command you showed.

Comment: Known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234

Comment: In my case just *reboot* the Intellij IDEA and it automagically works......

Comment: Could happen when tryig to run `StreamLit` apps in `VSCode`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This can be fixed by manually adding in the `PATH` variables in PyCharm to the console.

1. Open your Anaconda cmd
2. [Activate your Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)
3. Get the full PATH value by typing `echo %PATH%`

   - if you are on Windows 7/can't copy the output, cd the cmd to your desktop and type `echo %PATH% > path_val.txt`
   - this will create a txt file so you can copy/paste the values easier.
4. In PyCharm, go to **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console -> click the folder on the right of Environment variables.**
5. Click the plus button to add a new Environment Variable

   - The name should be `PATH`
   - The value is the entire output from the `echo %PATH%` command above.
6. Click OK, then apply.

Comment: I'm the original OP and now I try to follow your steps in PyCharm Community 2019.1 version and I simply cannot paste the output from echo %PATH%. It just doesn't paste.

Comment: It looks like PyCharm now expects the pasted value to contain the variable name, an equals sign, and then the variable value. In your terminal, type echo PATH=%PATH%|clip. This will copy the format PyCharm expects, then you can click the Paste button on the environment variables screen.

Comment: Why do you need to activate conda environment? what exactly is it doing, is it like creating virtual environment?

Comment: Because the OP is using a new Anaconda environment, the path to the interpreter is different. You can try it for yourself, type echo %PATH% in a the base environment and then run the command again after activating a different one - the output will be different. Yes to the latter question; these environments are Anaconda's implementation of virtual environments.

Comment: Had to make this change in the specific module Run Configuration (added the PATH environment variable)

Comment: For me this did not work. However, doing the same but pasting the PATH into the environment variables of the run configuration did work.

Answer (score 143):

I have answerd this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none/60342954#60342954), to my understanding this error is caused by the missing/misplacement of **libcrypto** file in anaconda3/DLLs folder:

> From `anaconda3\Library\bin` **copy** below files and **paste** them in `anaconda3/DLLs`:

```
-   libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
-   libssl-1_1-x64.dll
```

Comment: This works, when you have already set up the paths and still error occurs.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me When I had this problem just in of my "miniconda" environments. So I copied the files you mentioned from `C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\<my_conda_environment>\Library\bin` and paste them into `C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\<my_conda_environment>\DLLs` and now PyCharm connects to console.

Comment: I added the anaconda3\Library\bin to path and it worked for me

Comment: Worked for Windows Server 2016 with Anaconda 2020.02. I hate Windows.

Comment: Searching for this issue always ends up with the "you need to set PATH yourself" solutions in my case. The PATH stuff did nothing for me. Your solution saved the day.

Comment: This solution worked for my users in US. I have no idea why. I didnt have to make this step on my own computer. Many Thanks

Comment: After 3 days of trying all sorts of things, this finally worked! Thank you so much :)

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than the other solutions of manually mucking around with your PATH. Those will always come back to bite you (e.g. if you end up with different virtual environment activated to the place you've pointed your PATH).

Comment: I've added the dll in the DLLs folder inside my environment folder (not Anaconda3 one) and it seemed to work. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! This simple explanation solved my problem, though it is not related to environments, the core problem was based on the same principle. Great solution!

Comment: Thanks! Just a heads-up: in case it doesn't work straight away, close and reopen your shell.

Comment: For me (on Windows 10), copying these files into any folder has not worked. Instead, what worked was installing OpenSSL from this link https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and selecting the option to copy the files into the Windows system folder (it seems like libcrypto/libssl files were present somewhere else on my path)

Answer (score 34):

You can try to set system environment variables, like "C:\Python\Anaconda3;C:\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
C:\Python\Anaconda3\Library\bin;".

Only "C:\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts;" is not enough, and it works to me.

Comment: Why comment? This is exactly the answer I needed. Adding `C:\Python\Anaconda3\Library\bin` fixed my problem. And python -c 'import ssl' now works.

Comment: Can't up vote this enough! I was having a bunch of trouble getting python to run from Matlab on a Windows machine. Kept complaining about how it couldn't find `dll` stuff. Turns out it wasn't Matlab...it was the system paths. I added those often recommended, but still didn't work. The key was this solution....add the `Library\bin" path

Comment: Was the solution also with "miniforge"

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 Pro x64 and PyCharm CE 2018.3

**A solution that worked for me**: Re-install Anaconda3 for all users (with Admin priveledges) and choose "add python.exe to Path" (even though it is nor recommended). Then PyCharm connected successfully without this error.

**A work around that also worked**: Use another environment (pyenv or conda). It worked for me when I faced the same issue on

**Some other suggestions I saw on Internet**:
run `Anaconda3\Scripts>conda update --all`
but this threw the HTTP connection error rises, which might be related.

Answer (score 8):

if running under a virtual env  (i.e. your have issued the command: conda activate <env_name>)

The files (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll) to copy are found under:
C:\USER<username>.conda\envs<env_name>\Library\bin

They have to be copied into:
C:\USER<username>.conda\envs<env_name>\DLLs

Comment: Thanks. This helped for me :) Other solutions did not work by themselves

Comment: Also worked for me, other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me, but instead it was a problem with OpenSSL on Windows 10 Enterprise. I fixed it by downloading and installing OpenSSL from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: My case as well!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error was a result of spinning pipenv from non-base conda env. Setting variable in PyCharm or moving files in base anaconda structure didn't help, because PyCharm looked for these DLLs in my conda env in the middle.

So I had to move files from base conda structure:
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin

To my conda env from which I spinned the final Pipenv I use in PyCharm:
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs<conda_env_name>\DLLs

The files I had to move to have IPython work correctly:

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.exe
```

The reason is that not all libraries/binaries are propagated to the virtual envs. Virtual envs are able to find these files in "root Python". Venvs stay lighter thanks to not copying them.

However, PyCharm gets confused in a setup such as mine, and treats the conda env in the middle as a "root Python", and can't find the libraries/bins. This problem can potentially make itself apparent with other dlls or bins.

It may be worth to move all missing files this way.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer!
This works definately.

I have answerd this here, to my understanding this error is caused by the missing/misplacement of libcrypto file in anaconda3/DLLs folder:

From anaconda3\Library\bin copy below files and paste them in anaconda3/DLLs:

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and my main IDE is Sublime Text 4.

> Environment: Windows 10 with Anaconda

> What I needed: **from cryptography.fernet import Fernet**

The marked solution was unachievable for me and the following answer solved it right away:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip uninstall pyopenssl cryptography
pip install pyopenssl cryptography
```

Validate with:

> python -v -c "from OpenSSL import SSL"

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/qatrack/c/24RB6hesOko?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

another solution: edit python3.7's site.py(in Lib dir):

```
from os.path import join, abspath, dirname
base_path = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
os.environ['PATH'] = '%s%s' % (
    os.environ['PATH'],
    join(base_path, 'Library', 'bin'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone is searching for Eclipse PyDev, It's same as Rob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240362/2350145).

No. 4 can be found at **Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreters -> Environment -> Click New** and add **PATH**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to Python 3.8 (with miniconda) and it did not work with Pycharm generating "anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error". I have tried several proposals here and tweaked env variables in different way w/o much success.
Finally I have updated to Pycharm 2020.2.3 and it worked like a charm, no tweaks ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to run a script with the task manager (windows 10). The script run well in the anaconda prompt but keep giving me this error in the windows console. The solution for me was to add new enviromental variables following this post https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html I hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

For me with python 3.8 it helped to change to interpreter type to "Custom environment" and using an already existing Anaconda environment within the dialog for a new project.

Environment: "Select existing"

Type: "Python"

Python path: Python 3.8.12 with the path to the executable in Anaconda3\envs

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35650514)