# from urllib3.util.ssl_ import ( ImportError: cannot import name ssl

Tags: python, python-2.7

My resources:

Python 2.7, Ubunutu 18.04, Pycharm, virtual box oracle

I have an automation solution built in python.
The solution can be run from both `cmd` or `pycharm` of course.
2 options to run automation solution.

```
python main.py args a,b,c...(run 1 suite of tests)
python jenkinsRun.py arg a,b,c...(run main.py with diff args each time -lets say 5 time for instance)
```

Once `jenkinsRun.py` is runnig it will execute each `main.py` like this:

```
os.system('python main.py %s %s %s %s %s %s'%(STD,config.VpcStackName, '-dryrun', 'false', '-tenant' ,config.PROD_STAGE_Tenant))
```

Note that this is how I implemented it 3 years ago..could be better ways like using `__import__`, but need way to pass arguments, etc...

Anyway, when run:

```
python main.py arg a,b,c..
```

All good.

When run:

```
jenkinsRun.py
```

which should run main each time with diff args I get exception:

```
"/home/ohad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 7, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name ssl
```

This happend only when I run the code on my new environment (see resources above)
last week I had old virtul box with ubuntu 15.04 (old) which everything worked well (didn't touch the vode ever since).

I have installed on new virtual box from scratch libaries, drivers, etc, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure: are you certain that you are invoking `Python 2.x` ? Ubuntu 18.04 has `3.x` as default, so make sure that you are not accidentally starting the script using another python version

Comment: Checking, but main run perfect, while jenkinsRun does not.

Comment: you were right! The pycharm interpettor was /usr/bin/python which is ok, but when it call os.system('python main bla bla ..) it pointed to /usr/local/bin/python.Thank a lot .BTW -how can i close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure: are you certain that you are invoking `Python 2.x` ?

`Ubuntu 18.04` has `Python 3.x` as default, so make sure that you are not accidentally starting the script using another python version.

Answer (score 19):

Could be some issue with installation. I did re-installed on MAC and it worked

```
sudo pip install awscli --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using boto3 as a dependency, there was a bug with how the boto3 dependencies were managed.

try running
`pip3 install boto3 --upgrade` to update boto3 and the issue should be resolved!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error after creating a new environment (which also uses Boto3). It turned out to be a DLL error (`ImportError: DLL load failed`), which was caught by SSL module resulting in the error from the question: `ImportError: cannot import name ssl`.

Solution for me was to add an additional folder to the path: `path_to_anaconda/Anaconda3/Library/bin`. In that way, DLL load succeeds and the given ImportError is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue came apparently from having colliding versions of `boto3`, `botocore` and `awscli`. This fixed the issue:

```
pip install boto3 botocore awscli aiobotocore --ignore-installed
```

As noted in the comments this can be really slow so I recommend to search for the compatible versions and tell pip to install them, for example:

```
pip install boto3==1.33.13 botocore==1.33.13 awscli==1.31.13 aiobotocore==2.9.0 --ignore-installed
```

Comment: This is maniacally slow as it tries to find the correct combinations of packages (downloading wheels and metadata). Recommend if you're using this method you use boto3==<version> etc. for each package once you know which ones are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in PyCharm when I hit this wall.

Solved it by redirecting the path to my Anaconda environment, which I keep better provisioned and up to date.

[image: Select Edit Configurations]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update the latest version of `awscli` resolved on my Mac by the below command line.

> curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2-2.0.30.pkg" -o

> "AWSCLIV2.pkg" sudo installer -pkg AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /

**Reference:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html#cliv2-mac-install-cmd

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling, installing, even creating environments... this worked for me!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405693

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on Win 10 and VS Code was pointing at the Conda interpreter. The issue was solved by installing Python 3.11 outside of Conda and pointing at the new interpreter. Don't forget to add the new Python to PATH and install boto3 afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Im able to slove the error with below change

```
From anaconda3\Library\bin copy below files and paste them in anaconda3/DLLs
```

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why it worked. But, I had this issue in AWS Glue, and I was able to get around this problem by using Glue 3.0 instead of Glue 2.0.

Answer (score -2):

Please update the latest urllib package:

run :

```
pip3 uninstall urllib3
pip3 install urllib3
```