# import _ssl error,DLL load failed ,Python 37 Anaconda Windows 10

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

I am struggling with _ssl issue on Win10.
I have moved python packages and code from Windows 7 to Windows 10. In the starting I was facing below issues :

> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

But this one got resolved via reinstalling .whl packages of numpy and pandas.

Currently I am facing below issue, while executing the code:

```
import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Referred to other Questions on Stack overflow and tried few steps:

1. Changed Path variables as advised in this [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import _ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)
2. Installed pyopenssl .
3. Updated the system Environment variables.
4. Restarted the pycharm.

Currently on Anaconda prompt It's showing as :

```
   (base) C:\>
   (base) C:\>python
    Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 14 2018, 19:12:50) [MSC v.1900 32 bit 
    (Intel)] :: Ana
     conda, Inc. on win32
     Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
     information.
   >>> import ssl
  >>> import _ssl
  >>>
```

which means there is no issue with _ssl.pyd file.

This is working perfectly fine on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "merged the code" please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import \_ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Pycharm forum [post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234) it's a known issue that will be fixed in the next release of Pycharm 2019.1. The only way to resolve this is to create an environment using python 3.6. If you use that environment as your interpreter PyCharm should work properly.

Cheers!!

Comment: @Hagbard for your reference .

Answer (score 3):

NO!! Of course you can keep using python 3.7 from PyCharm. There is another answer given for that question [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import _ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405693/5127304) which allows you to get rid of this issue by copy/paste of two dll files regarding _ssl procedure.

Comment: I am not sure about the current status of this Pycharm bug .But at the time if raising this question pasting DLL files did not help . Then I came across a forum post which I have mentioned in the answer . Downgrading the Python interpreter from 3.7 to 3.6 helped .

Comment: For your reference : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234