# Python "cannot import 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a Python script to run through a batch file for Windows Task Scheduler and I'm running into an error when running the file.

The code works in both my Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm, but fails when trying to run through a batch file.

Modules imported within the script:

```py
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
from IPython.display import HTML
```

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\jraines\Desktop>"C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\jraines\Downloads\Partners Email New.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jraines\Downloads\Partners Email New.py", line 27, in <module>
    region_name='us-east-1')
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyathena\__init__.py", line 54, in connect
    from pyathena.connection import Connection
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyathena\connection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 30, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\credentials.py", line 42, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import InstanceMetadataFetcher, parse_key_val_file
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 7, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py)
```

When I run my script in my Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm I don't see this error message, but when I run it on the command line I get the error above.  I do have the "C:\Users\jraines\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\ssl_.py" file installed as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599895/pycharm-importerror-when-importing-any-module-that-imports-ssl

Comment: You may be executing the code on different interpreters. Try `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in your script to verify which interpreter you use for each.

Answer (score 0):

I use this steps solved the issue. my python version is 3.7.4.

```sh
yum  install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel libffi-devel

reinstall python3.7.4
```

import ssl is ok