# PyCharm: Python Console throws ImportError when opening

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I just installed PyCharm on my Windows 10 laptop. When I opened the Python Console I got this message

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=<portNum>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 191.5701.26\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I originally had the last stable pycharm installed, but I uninstalled it and wne with this newer 2019 version. But the issue happened both times.

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)
So that is the solution. It was posted already. The annoying part is that the post suggests copying and pasting into the variables. But I couldn't copy and paste so I had to type it all in.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution posted in [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import _ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405693/5127304) which is about copying/pasting two dll files. It worked for me and the PyCharm connects to console without any problems!