# DLL load failed python 3.7

Tags: python

I just bought new computer (dell xps 15).

I installed anaconda with python 3.7 and pycharm.

when I run pycharm in the python console I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried:

1. download Visual Studio 2017
2. added  msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll to C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64
3. tried to install Visual C++ Redistributable but it says that another version of this product already installed.

what can I try next??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  read the solution proposed [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error) 
since it seems very similar to your problem (in brief: you need to set 
manually add the `PATH` variables in `PyCharm` to the console)