# Flask import error on app.py even though dependencies installed

Tags: python, flask

Using VScode
I have these three flask dependencies installed

```
Flask                              1.0.2
Flask-Cors                         3.0.7
Flask-PyMongo
```

When running app.py it still gives me an error.
my app.py code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

So when I access this url it is supposed to render index.html then run js associated with index.html right? It is giving me error as follows:

```
File "c:/Users/haneu/Desktop/MINE/Ind_Projects/full Stock prediction/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import cli, json
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 18, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import \_ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)