# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. I've tried all methods from other posts

Tags: python, flask

I am not sure why it is giving me this error and what I am lacking, error throws me is related to flask however I do have flask installed. error goes as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/haneu/Desktop/Data Analytics/Belly-Button-Biodiversity/StarterCode/Belly_Button_Biodiversity/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import cli, json
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 18, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\haneu\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried installing visual studio, setting environment path and others as suggests in other questions.

There are all the things I am importing:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: error shows it has problem with module `ssl` which you may have to install. It may also need C/C++ library like OpenSSL. They may not be installed with `flask` automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import \_ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)

Comment: as I said, I've tried the answer and didn't work.