# Warning: Pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available [Windows]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

Here is my problem.

First i only installed Anaconda to my Windows Pc and i am working with it, i can create environments in Anaconda etc. But the files are *ipynb,
I don't have another Python version on my Pc, only Anaconda and Python 3.9.12

Today i wanted to work on Python BOT which has *py files
so for this i wanted to create environments outside of Anaconda!

I created a bot folder on the Desktop
I opened CMD

```
python -m venv C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot
```

i opened this file from Visual Code.
On the therminal , Virsual Code activated my env

```
PS C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot> & c:/Users/Messi/Desktop/Bot/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

(Bot) PS C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot>

In Bot file i created another file and named it IG-Bot-main and in Virsual Code, i used `cd .\IG-Bot-main` to go that inside folder.

Lastly i used `pip install -r requirements.txt` this commnd but there are errors below

```
    (Bot) PS C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot> cd .\IG-Bot-main
(Bot) PS C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot\IG-Bot-main> pip install -r requirements.txt
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/selenium/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/selenium/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
(Bot) PS C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot\IG-Bot-main>
```

I don't want to install another python from https://www.python.org/downloads/
Should i install Download Python 3.10.6?
How can i fix this problem? why does this problem occur?

Thanks very much

Comment: have you tried installing ssl module?

Comment: How can i install it?

Comment: `pip install ssl`

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder Please do not give "advice" that doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609378/7976758

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder Not to say that even that broken module cannot be downloaded with `pip` from PyPI because pypi.org requires SSL and the OP doesn't have it.