# Cant start jupyter notebook in Anaconda3, because of error in import _ssl

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I just installed the latest Anaconda on windows 10 and wanted to start jupyter notebook with the anaconda prompt, but the following error occures. Although I think its a common problem I couldn't find a solution.

```
(base) C:\Users\Felix>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Addition: 
I cant use `pip` to install something. The following message occures

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import \_ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Either im too dumb to apply this to my case or it's not possible. (In addition: i dont use pycharm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the error in this case is that some incompatible DLLs are loaded before the Anaconda's DLLs. [One of the solutions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#solution) is to use a special Anaconda DLL loading mode by setting the corresponding control environment variable in the Anaconda prompt:

```
set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
```

P.S.: Not to set the variable on every startup manually, you can set it as a [system environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).