# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, ssl, visual-studio-code, importerror

I don't have much experience in programming, so I get confused with one problem, namely I cannot `import ssl`.
When I execute my project in `jupyter notebook` - it works fine. But as soon as I move to the `Visual Studio Code`, `import ssl` yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Git\pytroch_geometric\pytorch_geometric\examples\link_pred.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ssl 
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.
```

Could somebody explain to me the cause? I saw exactly the same problem [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue39344), but unfortunately I do know where to find the files they are talking about.

Thanks!

Comment: Eventually this answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405693/15452880 . The topic can be closed

Answer (score 1):

Add anaconda3\Library\bin to path in Environment Variables.