# Anaconda and jupyter notebook on Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

It just does not seem to work. I get several different errors.

System: Windows 10
Anaconda : 64 bit, latest download. Anaconda 3.
python: 3.9

1. For some reason ssl does not load. I have tried all the solutions proposed online, such as adding Anaconda3, Anaconda3\bin, Anaconda3\Lib to the PATH variable. Adding the Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1n-h2bbff1b_0\Library\bin to the PATH variable.
2. I do have the libssl-1_1-x64.dll.

The errors I get:

1. Neither Anaconda Navigator, nor the jupyter notebook starting scripts do anything. They just fail without any errors.
2. The only clue I have is when I start the python command prompt and try to "import ssl". I get the following error.

   'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.

   (base) C:\Users\kadambi>python
   Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaco
   nda, Inc. on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   > > > import ssl
   > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
   > > > File "", line 1, in 
   > > > File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
   > > > import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
   > > > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified procedure could
   > > > not be found.

When I try pip install pyopenssl, this is the error I get.

```
(base) C:\Users\kadambi>pip install pyopenssl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ss
module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in c:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-pac
ges (21.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-pa
ages (from pyopenssl) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.3 in c:\software\anaconda3\lib\
te-packages (from pyopenssl) (3.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-pa
ages (from cryptography>=3.3->pyopenssl) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-pac
ges (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3->pyopenssl) (2.21)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ss
module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirmi
 the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retr
s exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS
L because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

(base) C:\Users\kadambi>
```

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import _ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)

This post answers the question. Looks the the idiots of anaconda look for SSL and other dlls in C:\anacnoda3\dlls. They do not use the windows path resolution. I guess they do not trust Windows to do the right thing.

Copying the ssl and crypto dlls to Anaconda3\Dlls location solved the problem.