# Error occurred while reading WSGI handler (Flask, Pymongo)

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, iis-10, wfastcgi

I have developed a web application with Flask that connects to a MongoDB database. Now that I have tried deploying to a Windows IIS environment. I have received an error when I display the application in the browser.

Here I indicate in the image the file tree of the "aplicativoflask" project. App.py is the main script.

[image]

I am using python 3.9.13 and Flask 1.1.2 and wfastcgi 3.0.0

Here I show the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="App.py" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\websites\applicativoflask" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="App.app" lockItem="false" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I should point out that I installed Python with Anaconda (I didn't directly install python).

Here is the error I get:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "App.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File "C:\websites\applicativoflask\.\App.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pymongo import (
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pymongo.client_options import _parse_ssl_options
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\client_options.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pymongo.pool import PoolOptions
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.
```

I request your support to interpret the error and provide a solution. Big thanks for any comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.7 anaconda environment - import \_ssl DLL load fail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error)

Comment: According to your description, you have deployed the application to IIS and received the error. Do you get the same error when running the application in your local development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to copy the following files from directory `anaconda3\Library\bin` to `anaconda3/DLLs`.

> libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
>
> libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Then recall the command and open the webpage.

Comment: Yes thanks friend. This comment solved my problem. I should add that this problem occurs ONLY when install python through Anaconda. If you install Python directly, both packages (libcrypto and libssl), there been installed correctly. And the problem does not happen.